# Javascript min files missing semicolon cause bundler to create invalid javascript

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

We use many javascript libraries which we fetch with Nuget. Unfortunately, some of these libraries (amplify and linq) is missing a semicolon at the end of their .min versions.

Is there a way to make the bundler detect and add these missing semicolons?

I do not want to modify the script directly, because I will forget it at next Nuget update.

Comment: Run into the same issue recently, but unfortunately I ended with locating the missing semicolons manually. You might open an issue to the according third party projects you are using...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the [bundletransformer](https://bundletransformer.codeplex.com/) project instead of standard asp.net transformers.
It seems they had a similar issue, but already resolved it as described in this [Issue](https://bundletransformer.codeplex.com/workitem/15).